# Mapping joined Domain Model to View Model using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

In my business logic class I am joining two data models and returning back to the controller as IEnumerable. I need to map these collection to the List using automapper .But it is not working as expected.

***Logic class***

```
 public IEnumerable<object> GetPurchaseOrderDetailsByPersonId(long personId)
    {
        var purchaseOrderDetails = from pom in _unitOfWork.DbSet<PurchaseOrderMain>()
                                   join rep in _unitOfWork.DbSet<RepresentativeMaster>() on pom.REPM_ID equals rep.REPM_ID
                                   where pom.REPM_ID == personId
                                   select new { pom.RM_ID,pom.OrderNo,pom.OrderAmount,pom.OrderDate ,rep.RepName };

        return purchaseOrderDetails;
    }
```

***Controller***

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<object> purchaseOrder = _CLS_PurchaseOrder_BLL.GetPurchaseOrderDetailsByPersonId(PersonId).ToList();

        return View(purchaseOrder.ToEntity<OMOS.Models.PurchaseOrderDetails>());
    }
```

***ToEntity() in  extension class***

```
  public static List<TDestination> ToEntity<TDestination>(this List<object> OBJSource)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<object, TDestination>();
        List<TDestination> destination = new List<TDestination>();//Handling the null destination
        foreach (object source in OBJSource)
        {
            destination.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<object, TDestination>(source));
        }
        return destination;
    }
```

But resulted mapping is not as expected.

Comment: Why are you using `object` instead of the actual class? Automapper isn't going to be able to map to object as it's probably not going to share any properties that `PurchaseOrderDetails` has.

Comment: Since it is one or more classes joined , i don't have the actual class.it is anonymous type of one or more joined.

Comment: Then you need to creates some sort of wrapping class for this.

Comment: There will be a lot of joining like this. Do i need to create wrapping classes for all these query results?

Comment: Automapper works by comparing the properties of one type to another and then automatically mapping them based on name and type. In this instance, you might be better off just manually mapping the properties yourself. It will be faster (when running) and also saves all the mapping classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
public static List<TDestination> ToEntity<TDestination>(this List<object> OBJSource)
    {
        List<TDestination> destination = new List<TDestination>();//Handling the null destination

        foreach (object source in OBJSource)
            destination.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<TDestination>(source));

        return destination;
    }
```